# Azure DevOps agent pool role assignments using the API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm currently working on automating role assignments for agent pools in Azure DevOps using the API.
I've managed to retrieve role assignments successfully using the following commands:

```
base64AuthInfo=$(echo -n ":$PAT" | base64)
headers=(
    "Authorization: Basic $base64AuthInfo"
    "Content-Type: application/json"
)

uri="https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.agentqueuerole/roleassignments/resources/$projectId_$queueId?api-version=7.0-preview"

curl -X GET -H "${headers[0]}" -H "${headers[1]}" "$uri"
```

However, when I try to use a PUT request to assign a user a role on the agent pools, it doesn't seem to work.

Here are the commands I'm using for the PUT request:

```
base64AuthInfo=$(echo -n ":$PAT" | base64)
headers=(
    "Authorization: Basic $base64AuthInfo"
    "Content-Type: application/json"
)

payload='{
    "identity": {
        "id": "$userId"
    },
    "role": {
        "identifier": "distributedtask.agentqueuerole.Reader"
    }
}'

uri="https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.agentqueuerole/roleassignments/resources/$projectId_$queueId?api-version=7.0-preview"

curl -X PUT -H "${headers[0]}" -H "${headers[1]}" -d "$payload" "$uri"
```

The output of the PUT request indicates that no changes were made:

```
{
  "count": 0,
  "value": []
}
```

Are there any specific headers, parameters, or payload modifications needed for the PUT request to properly assign a role to a user on an agent pool in Azure DevOps?

It's worth noting that I can assign roles via the UI, so I have the permission to do so.

Thank you!